# How to keep the taskbar icon while switching PyQt Window?

Tags: python, pyqt4

In my PyQt GUI app, I have two main windows. I'm using the hide() and show() methods to switch between them. The problem is that when I switch from the starting window to its child, the taskbar icon disappears, and reappears when I switch from the child window to the starting window.

I'm using this function to create a child window, and a similar one to go back.

```
def createPlayWindow(self):
    self.playWindow = PlayWindow(self.profile, False, self)
    self.hide()
    self.playWindow.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a window has a parent, it won't get it's own taskbar entry. So don't give the other window a parent.